# Dynamic naming of variable (E1, E2, E3 ...)

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I was wondering if there is a way or a library I can use to do the following:

I have an arraylist of objects where each obj has a name.

The list needs to always be unique with a maximum of 5 elements like `[E1,E2,E3]`

If for example the list has initial form `[E3,E5]` and I add an object, its name should be E1 and the list will be `[E1,E3,E5]` or `[E3,E5,E1]` it doesn't matter, as long as the name is unique and the item is added to the list starting from 1 to 5.

If add another item, it should be `[E3,E5,E1,E2]`, always a unique name and between 1 and 5

These are my failed attempts,

```java
StartNode node = new StartNode();
node.setName("E1");

for (int i = 0; i < circuit.getNbStartNodes(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= circuit.getNbStartNodes(); j++) {
        String test = ((StartNode) circuit.getStartNode(j)).getName();
        if (("E"+j).equalsIgnoreCase(test) && ("E"+j).equalsIgnoreCase(node.getName()) ) {
            break;
        }
        else
            node.setName("E" + j);
    }
}

/*while (t <= circuit.getNbStartNodes()) {
      for (int j = 0; j < circuit.getNbStartNodes(); j++) {
          String test = ((StartNode) circuit.getStartNode(j)).getName();
          if (("E" + t).equalsIgnoreCase(test) || ("E" + t).equalsIgnoreCase(node.getName()))
              break;
          else {
              node.setName("E" + t);
          }
      }
      t++;
  }
*/

/*  for (int i = 1; i <= circuit.getNbStartNodes(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < circuit.getNbStartNodes(); j++) {
            String test = ((StartNode) circuit.getStartNode(j)).getName();
            if (!("E" + i).equalsIgnoreCase(test)) {
                node.setName("E" + i);
                t=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (t==0)
            break;
        else
            continue;
*/
//String test = ((StartNode) circuit.getStartNode(i)).getName();
//for (int j = 1; j <= circuit.getNbStartNodes(); j++) {
//    if (!("E" + j).equalsIgnoreCase(test))
//       node.setName("E" + j);
//}
```

What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: I was wondering, if your initial list contains `E3` and `E5`, does it matter *which* element will be added? Does it have to be `E1`, or is any of `E1`, `E2` or `E4` fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a small boolean array to track which names are already used and populate it with accordingly
- Find the first unused element and use it as id.

```java
boolean[] used = new boolean[circuit.getNbStartNodes()];

for (int i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(((StartNode) circuit.getStartNode(j)).getName().substring(1)) - 1; // should be   in range 0..4
    used[index] = true;
}

String name = "E";
for (int i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
    if (!used[i]) {
        name += String.valueOf(i + 1); // starting from 1
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("free name: " + name);
StartNode node = new StartNode();
node.setName(name);

// add new node to circuit, etc.
```

Comment: if for example all used is all true, the second loop doesn't get executed, do you think i can initiate an array of boolean which contains my already exisiting nodes that will turn to true and the remaining will be left as false, so that way the second loop gets executed ? also i think it's missing

`for (int j = 0; j < circuit.getNbStartNodes(); j++) {` for the first loop

Comment: The idea of `used` is to track which nodes are used, by default all elements of this array are `false`.  If after the first loop no free space is left, the second loop will run anyway.  The size of `used` is the same as `circuit.getNbStartNodes()`, so it does not matter which value should be used in the first loop (no need to call a method if there is an equal `used.length`).

Answer (score 1):

With small values, Alex' solution works fine.

However, if you ever come across a use case where the number of elements become potentially large, then you could use a `TreeSet` to keep track of the unused numbers. Further, the `nextCeilValue` is the next number to pick when there are no removed numbers.

In the below code, I have created a `UniqueNumber` class, which is able to `get` the next number, or `remove` a given number. Note that this code provides integers starting from 0. Of course, you could easily convert this to your E-numbers using the function `i -> "E" + (i + 1)`.

```java
public class UniqueNumber {

    private int nextCeilValue;

    private final TreeSet<Integer> removedNumbers = new TreeSet<>(Integer::compare);

    public int get() {
        if (removedNumbers.isEmpty()) {
            return nextCeilValue++;
        }
        else {
            int number = removedNumbers.first();
            removedNumbers.remove(number);
            return number;
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(int number) {
        if (number < 0 || number > nextCeilValue) {
            return false;
        }

        if (number == nextCeilValue) {
            nextCeilValue--;
        }
        else {
            removedNumbers.add(number);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int size() {
        return nextCeilValue - removedNumbers.size();
    }
}
```

In order to test this, we first need to simulate your initial situation. In our integer-starting-from-zero-world, we need the numbers 2 and 4 (representing E3 and E5). In below code, we need to call `get` five times, and then remove element 0, 1 and 3. Of course, we could have created a `UniqueNumber(int... initialValues)` constructor which does this under the hood.

```java
UniqueNumber un = new UniqueNumber();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    un.get();
}
un.remove(0); // Remove E1
un.remove(1); // Remove E2
un.remove(3); // Remove E4
```

In order to get the next value, simply use this:

```java
StartNode node = new StartNode();
node.setName("E" + (un.get() + 1));
```

Comment: thank you sir, i'll use this one for my gates, as i'll be having a maximum of 50 gates.